# Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception

I want to show image from url I used bitmap but image not showing but got null pointer exception  please help me.I am showing it in list view text is showing properly but only image not showing

```
  public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

    Context context;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
            List<RowItem> items) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
       // TextView txtTitle;
        TextView name;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
          convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            /*holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);*/
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.name.setText(rowItem.getName());
     //   holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());


        //holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());

        Bitmap bitMap=downloadImage(rowItem.getImageUrl());
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitMap);
//        holder.imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
        return convertView;
    }



    private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream stream = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

        try {
            stream = getHttpConnection(url);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.
                    decodeStream(stream, null, bmOptions);
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
    private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
            throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = null;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConnection.connect();

            if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stream;
    }
}
```

Log cat

```
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at com.example.gdirectory.CustomListViewAdapter.downloadImage(CustomListViewAdapter.java:80)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at com.example.gdirectory.CustomListViewAdapter.getView(CustomListViewAdapter.java:60)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:736)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1655)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:349)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-13 04:17:09.349: E/AndroidRuntime(3236):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Would you be so kind to post the logcat, please?

Comment: What line in your code generated the null pointer exception?

Comment: My guess: the url is not valid (response code not HTTP_OK), so the `stream` object is null.

Comment: its not a good way to download image from Main thread. first put Network task on background thread, and then check the response stream.

Comment: method `getHttpConnection` is returning `NULL`. cross check this condition `if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            }` is not becoming true.

Comment: Praveen Sharma Thanks i solved that using background thread

Answer (score 0):

Probably our URL is not valid and getHttpConnection return null. Then when you try to close InputStreem you got NullPointerException.

You should post error log that printed at getHttpConnection methot. Then we'll can say what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please change it into

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

    Context context;
    private List<RowItem> items;
    public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
            List<RowItem> items) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.items= items;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
       // TextView txtTitle;
        TextView name;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;


        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
          convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            /*holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);*/
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.name.setText(items.get(position).getName());

        Bitmap bitMap=downloadImage(items.get(position).getImageUrl());
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitMap);
        return convertView;
    }



    private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream stream = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

        try {
            stream = getHttpConnection(url);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.
                    decodeStream(stream, null, bmOptions);
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
    private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
            throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = null;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConnection.connect();

            if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stream;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have put an if statement and changed stream's value but if the condition if false stream would be null `if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            }`. So add an else statement and change the value of stream from null to a value.

Hope it helps! Good Luck with your project!

Answer (score -1):

The nullpointer occurs somewhere in in the downloadImage() method. On line 80, place a breakpoint there and you'll have more knowledge about the situation. The URL is probably not valid or null.

Comment: you must put this as a comment.

Comment: stream.close(); this is line i got exception

Comment: Not stream are coming thats why. you are calling stream.close() on null stream.

Comment: And one more thing when you one time consume the stream. it is finished.